# loop through a javascript array add the value to another array

Tags: javascript, react-native

how to loop through this array , I want to loop and and add name value to an empty array , when I console .log it gives the results below, could you please help , the result of my code is empty array

> this.props.names
>    it shows
>
> (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] 0: {name: "abc", id: 1} 1: {name: "def", id: 2} 2:
>   {name: "gh", id: 3} length: 3
>   **proto**: Array(0)

```
let titles = []
let cats = []
 cats = this.props.names
 let len = this.props.names.length;
 for( i = 0 ;i< cats.length ; i++){
    titles.push(cats[i].id)
 }

return titles;
```

Comment: `1< cats.len` should be `i< cats.length` but you can do it more readable with map: `const titles=cats.map(cat=>cat.id)`

Comment: its corrected , but still empty array as results

Comment: Try using `length` instead of `len` or even better; use the map.

Comment: could you please post some data samples ? EX : `this.props.names=[a,b,c,d]` and the expected and current result `Expected result:[x,y,z]; current result : [e,r,t]`

Comment: You could basically replace all the code posted here with `return this.props.names.map(cat=>cat.id)`

Comment: There's no `var` or `let` in front of `i = 0`. Is that declared somewhere else?

Comment: Please use `console.log(JSON.stringify(cats))` right after you set `cats` so that the proper structure is presented. Also, it may be that `this.props.names` does not have elements at the time you run this code... `console.log` shows you the value when you click on the down arrow, not at the moment it was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what i see... do

```js
let titles = []
let cats = [{name: "abc", id: 1},{name: "def", id: 2},{name: "gh", id: 3}]
 for( var p = 0 ;p< cats.length ; p++){
    titles.push(cats[p].id)
 }

console.log(titles)
```

Comment: added snippet .

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to extract the ids, and props and/or names may be empty or null, you can do it using `map`:

```
const titles = (props && props.names || []).map(val => val.id);
```

Here `props && props.names || []` will be equal to `[]` if `props` or `props.names` evaluates to falsy. That way, you can still apply `map` to it, which will return an empty array in this case.

```js
function demo(props) {
  const titles = (props && props.names || []).map(val => val.id);
  console.log(titles);
}

demo({ names: [{name: 'one', id: 1}, {name: 'two', id: 2}, {name: 'three', id: 3}] });
demo({ names: [] });
demo({});
demo(null);
```

See the [MDN doc about the map operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: How would this help if `props` is empty?